# Filter proxies from an HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, ecmascript-6, proxies

I am making an open-source proxy scraper that requests to an URL, gets the body, check if it's proxies etc...

How ever, this only works from a RAW text. And I want to filter **ALL proxies** from the recieved HTML.

```js
filterProxies(text) {
    if (typeof (text) == 'string') {
        let regx = /^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?:\s+|\s*:\s*)(\d{2,5})$/img;
        return [...text.matchAll(regx)]
    } else {
        throw new Error('\'.filterProxies(text)\': "text" is not an String.');
    }
}
```

this regex works to check if a string is a proxy, but does not work when I try to filter the proxies.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample input and expected output using regex

Comment: from
```html
<a>127.0.0.1:4000</a><div>127.0.0.1:4100</div>
```
to
```js
> ['127.0.0.1:4000', '127.0.0.1:4100']
```

Comment: `var str = "<a>127.0.0.1:4000</a><div>127.0.0.1:4000</div>";
var out = str.match(/\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}:\d{1,4}/g);
console.log(out);`. - Does this work for you ?

Comment: Those aren't "proxies", merely IPv4 addresses with a port number, although you never name it like that. Ports can vary from 1 to 65535 (yes, even 1 or 5 digits). What about IPv6 addresses? What about invalid addresses (555.318.998.001)? Why does your own regex allow spaces( i.e. `0.0.0.0   :00` would be found)?

Comment: I know, I just want to be able to take anything that looks like an IP from the HTML

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = '<a>127.0.0.1</a> '
        + '<b>127.0.0.1:4000</b> '
        + '<div>127.0.0.1:4100</div> '
        + '<err1>001.2.3.4</err1> '
        + '<err2>1.2.3.4444</err2> '
        + '<err3>1.2.3.256</err3>';
let regex1 = /\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(:\d{1,5})?/g;
let result1 = str.match(regex1);
console.log('result1: '+ JSON.stringify(result1, null, ' '));

let regex2 = /(?<!\d)([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}(:\d{1,5})?(?!\d)/g;
let result2 = str.match(regex2);
console.log('result2: '+ JSON.stringify(result2, null, ' '));
```

Console output:

```
result1: [
 "127.0.0.1",
 "127.0.0.1:4000",
 "127.0.0.1:4100",
 "001.2.3.4",
 "1.2.3.444",
 "1.2.3.256"
]
result2: [
 "127.0.0.1",
 "127.0.0.1:4000",
 "127.0.0.1:4100"
]
```

Explanation:

- the input string has 6 addresses, 3 with valid range, 3 with invalid range
- regex1 does a simple ipv4 address detection, without range check, with optional port number
- regex2 does a ipv4 address detection with proper byte range check 0...255, with optional port number
- regex2 does not check the range of the port number, it can be done the same way like the byte check
- detail on regex2:
- `(?<!\d)` - start with negative lookbehind to exclude a digit
- `([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` - OR'ed patterns of 0-9, 10-99, 100-199, 200-249, 250-255
- `(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}` - followed by 3 instances of a dot and same OR'ed pattern as before
- `(:\d{1,5})?` - followed by optional port number
- `(?!\d)` - negative lookahead to make sure there is no digit

The regex could be enhanced to support ipv6